# Use C# to read Avro data from S3 on AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, avro

I'm trying to code a very basic C# console app to read from a bucket in AWS. The file I'm trying to read is in the avro format.

At this point I have a console program with the nuget packages for AWSSDK.s3, AWSSDK.Core, and the avro package from Apache.

I know how to get a list of files in the bucket. So I can connect to AWS. I guess what I need to do now is figure out how to deserialize the data.

The final goal is to load the data into an SQL Server table. The files I'm working with are not very large.

We are working with another company on this project and they are sending us this data in the avro format.

I'm completely new to AWS programming and never heard of avro until about a week ago. Finding information on the internet has been kind of hard.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to read object data from an Amazon S3 bucket using the AWS SDK for .NET. You can use the **client.GetObjectAsync** method to read the data. See this example in Github:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/dotnetv3/S3/GetObjectExample/GetObjectExample/GetObject.cs

For your use case, you would need to use a lib like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Avro/ to handle the Avro requirements. As this is a very specific use case, I doubt you will find this specific example on the Internet.

Comment: Ok. I was able to read the contents of the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you got that part working with the AWS SDK for .NET